# Cordova receive shared data from other app

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

At first please do not mar this question as duplicate. All other questions are old and I've tried solutions from most of them and none of them work.

I'm working on an Android app and I'd added my app to share Android menu. I'd like to add functionality so if user clicks my app on the share list e.g. in Chrome browser or Google Drive app, my app will receive the data from that app e.g. from Chrome it wold be URL.

I've tried to use different plugins and read many posts about how to use intent in my app. Unfortunately none of them work.
I've tried:

- [Sending url to ionic android app via webintents from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856046/sending-url-to-ionic-android-app-via-webintents-from-another-app/34444688#34444688) - this one looked very promising
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap-webintent
- https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent - this one looked promising as well
- https://github.com/okwei2000/webintent
- https://github.com/stample/cordova-sharingreceptor

Did anyone got this working?
My AndroidManifest.xml is as follows - the part about intent:

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In my config.xml I have:

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

And I'm not getting data I'm expecting.

When I'm using https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent plugin I'm getting the intent but clipItems element is missing and the plugin is useless.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've done it.
I used https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent ver 0.1.3 and

```
window.plugins.intent.setNewIntentHandler(function (intent) {
    // To get browser URL I had to use
    var subject = intent.extras['android.intent.extra.SUBJECT'];
    var url = intent.extras['android.intent.extra.TEXT'];
    // For Chrome, Opera and FireFox it works. For build in Android browser TEXT holds page title and URL joined with +
});
```

Although ver 0.1.3 has

```
window.plugins.intent.getRealPathFromContentUrl(contentUrl, function (realPath) {}, function () {});
```

available I couldn't use it because this didn't give me the data I wanted. contentUrl is different for differen browsers e.g. for Chrome it is uri and for build in Android browser it's text.

I installed ver 0.1.3 using CLI

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent.git#61a47ae8c28a62004eeff4ed96a6f3c64c271a16
```

I couldn't add it using  tag in config.xml

I hope this will help others.

Comment: is it working in both ios and android. I am trying to implement the same in my app

Comment: It works on Android. I didn't test it on iOS. But feel free to add comment if you will test it on iOS.

Comment: Sure. What do you need?

Comment: adding our app to share menu and how to handle the action from there?

Comment: I'll update my answer later. I need to get to my office.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136422/discussion-between-varun-aaruru-and-strabek).

Comment: @LucaC. I don't know. I do not use it any more so don't have a chance to test it. Maybe other users will advise.