# How to show my ionic 2 app as an option to open a vcf file using intent-filter

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, ionic-native, vcf-vcard

I want my ionic 2 app to be able to show up as an option to open vcf file. Whenever user clicks on a .vcf file in android, usually default contact application launches but I want to launch my ionic 2 app. I also need to read content of vcf file from my app.

I know that there are intent plugins available for ionic. But I don't know how to use them, I got confused when I read the documentation of this plugins.

It would be nice if someone could suggest some intent filter plugins and explain a way to use this plugins to achieve my goal

Thanks

Comment: don't have the time for a proper answer but this may help you : https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/101/how-to-list-your-cordova-app-in-open-with-menu-in-android-and-handle-the-intent-event

Comment: @Dijish U.K Please have a look at this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712312/make-ionic-app-appear-in-share-list-and-receive-data/43867316#43867316

Comment: You can use node package into angualr 4+ i.e node-vcard parses that help us  vCard data into nice JSON

Comment: @Dijish U.K any update on this?