# How to share an image from external app to an Ionic 4 app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to share an image using the "share with" function from another app to my Ionic 4 app. My app has to handle the image and use it.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712312/make-ionic-app-appear-in-share-list-and-receive-data) solution but it is for Ionic 3. The plugins seems to be not mantained anymore.
There has to be a solution for such a common task in Ionic 4.

I've tried the [darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent](https://github.com/darryncampbell/darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent) without success.
My code is

```
    initializeApp() {
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                (<any>window).plugins.intentShim.registerBroadcastReceiver({
                    filterActions: [
                        'com.darryncampbell.cordova.plugin.broadcastIntent.ACTION'
                    ],
                    filterCategories: [
                        'android.intent.category.DEFAULT',
                    ],
                }, (intent) => {
                    //your code to be executed after the broadcast is received..
                    console.log('Received Intent: ' + JSON.stringify(intent.extras));
                });
            //more code...
```

This code do nothing. Nothing at all. Iwas able to edit my config.xml to configure the manifest so my app shows up in the share with menus. This works well.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: have you find any solution for this.. ;)

Comment: Not yet. Its very frustating.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was late replay, but thought it will help someone..

We used [`cordova-plugin-openwith`](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-openwith#installation) plugin to achieve this, where this helps us to share an image using the "share with" function from another app to our Ionic 4 app.

We can initialize the plugin with below code in constructor of the **App Component**.

```
     // Initialize the plugin
     window.plugins.openwith.init((initSuccess) => {
          console.log('init success!' + initSuccess);
     }, (initError) => {
          console.log('init failed: ' + initError);
     });
```

We can add event handlers then after..

```
     window.plugins.openwith.addHandler((intent) => {
           console.log('intent received');

           let fileType = '';
           for (const item of intent.items) {
              // const item = intent.items[i];
              console.log('  type: ', item.type);   // mime type
              console.log('  uri:  ', item.uri);
           }
     });
```

Hope this helps.. :)