# ionic: how to add our app to share menu?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I want to receive text from other applications in my mobile.For that i need to add my app to `share via` menu. In android native applications we do this with `intent-filters` and handle the `intent` in activity file. Now is there any possible way to do this in ionic framework.

> note: I am not asking about `ionic-social-sharing` plugin.I want to
>   receive from other applications. I tried searching in google for
>   plugins but no use.

[image: i want to add my app icon in this screen]

I want to add my app icon in this screen and handle the event.

Comment: this is the exact question i asked yesterday!! still no resolutions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384763/sharing-photo-photos-to-my-ionic-2-application-from-share-button-in-gallery-im

Comment: I even asked in forum but no reply @devanshsadhotra

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ionic-deeplinks/ also check https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks

Comment: no not deep linking. deep linking is to open your app from other app or open a link of your website in your app without opening in browser.

Comment: same here , even i asked in forum , and the reply was "let us knw if u get a solution!"

Comment: @varunaaruru  u saw the answer below ??it worked for me !!

Comment: @devanshsadhotra i was not able to install the plugin.. i am getting "moved to master" error

Comment: Hello , I want to use this functionality.. Any solutions guys?

Comment: This answer might resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43867316/1409009

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a question from 2017 but still hard to find the answer to so if you got here, there you go:
https://github.com/carsten-klaffke/send-intent
This should work for you.