# ionic3 get cordova Intent is not working properly

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic3

I use get intent and in that the path i get is the path of an image, which is shared from a gallery. But my problem is that i did not pass the value of path in global variable. I did try each and every thing. Also all data come in intend is form of JSON.

```js
window['plugins'].intent.getCordovaIntent(
  function (Intent) {
    var image= Intent
    var result= image.clipItems;
    alert("without="+result[0].uri)
    path= result[0].uri;
  }, 
  function () {
    console.log('Error');
  }
);
```

[Sharing photo/photos to my ionic 2 application from “share” button in gallery images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384763/sharing-photo-photos-to-my-ionic-2-application-from-share-button-in-gallery-im)

https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent

Comment: today i get 'uri' get  from intend but it is not absolute path i get path like this content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F63131

Comment: i solve that not proper way i able share only gallery image not for other app like whatsapp,gmail,etc